# Transferring an android game from one developer console to another on playstore

Tags: android, mobile, google-play, google-play-console

I am a beginner and have some very basic questions:

1: The old account has some reviews and replies from the dev account. What will happen to those after the transfer (will the reply from dev account still be there and just the name of the account will be changed?)

2: The new account is created after the game was published on the old account. How will that match up in the account details and will there be a mismatch in the display of game publishing and account creation date?

3: Will the previous account have no link whatsoever to the game after the transfer?

Thank you :)

Comment: Transfer an App from one Account to another is NOT possible.

Comment: @emandt It is possible. Google has a process for that.

Comment: @AlexanderHoffmann Yes there's a proper process and documentation. It's just that the answers to these questions are not clearly mentioned on the relevant pages for google play help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1: The old account has some reviews and replies from the dev account.
> What will happen to those after the transfer (will the reply from dev
> account still be there and just the name of the account will be
> changed?)

Yes. All reviews and answers will be migrated over to the new account. The answers will look like they were posted from the new account.

> 2: The new account is created after the game was published on the old
> account. How will that match up in the account details and will there
> be a mismatch in the display of game publishing and account creation
> date?

I'm not sure if and how this will be visible to users. Looking at a listing I don't even see the original published date anymore, just the date the app was last updated. In my case that date is before the migration to the new account happened and the date is still correct. I can't find the date the account was created anywhere on the public-facing parts of the Play Store. I don't think you need to worry about this. :)

> 3: Will the previous account have no link whatsoever to the game after
> the transfer?

That's correct. It will be completely removed and inaccessible from the original account.

Comment: Right, also would anyone be able to ever tell if the game was published from the new account or transferred later from another?

Comment: I don't see how anyone would be able to do that. I still have access to two Play Store accounts we're we've done exactly this for a number of apps. I can't see anything in the old account after the transfer was completed, and there isn't anything (at least obvious) in the new account that indicates that the apps were transferred over rather than originally published there.

Comment: Thank you, that clears it all.